# Spring Thymleaf Datepicker not updating value

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

Expected:
on changing the datepickers selected date ajax sends the new date

what happens now: the initially setted date gets send even though the datepicker has a different date selected (image). javascript also logs just the setted date

I need to reload data on the change of the date. I tried using a form but formatting made it impossible  to use since java couldnt convert its own date back idk.

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {
    private Date dat = new Date(); //Wed Nov 29 14:01:31 CET 2023

    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    public String mainWithParam(String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("date", dat);
        return "welcome";
    }

    @PostMapping("/welcome/a")
    public String datePickerOnChange(Model model,
            @RequestParam String date) {
        System.out.println(date); //Wed Nov 29 14:01:31 CET 2023

        // TODO: date = newDate;
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

    <title>Spring Boot Thymeleaf Hello World Example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <td th:text="${#dates.format(date, 'dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm')}"></td>
        
        <div id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
           <div data-target="#date" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" 
            th:value="${#dates.format(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')}" id="datetimepicker1" placeholder="Date" 
            th:onchange="reloadAlleyOptions(this.getAttribute('data-date'))" th:data-date="*{date}"/>
                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar-alt"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function () {
        console.log("waiting for all requests to complete...");
    }).bind("ajaxStop", function () {
        location.reload();
    });

    function reloadAlleyOptions(date) {
        console.log(date)
        console.log("---")
        $.ajax({
            method: "post",
            type: "POST",
            url: "/welcome/a?date=" + date,
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function (e) {}
        });
    }
</script>

</html>
```

[image]